# When are captureStartValues and captureEndValues called in Android Transition?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-transitions

I am animating fragments using **custom transition animation**. For this, I have subclassed Transition and when Fragment view is created I assign `enterTransition` and `exitTransition` using `Transition` subclasses respectively. I see transition happening but without animations. I debugged it by putting breakpoints in `captureStartValues` and `captureEndValues` but it was never called. I wish to understand when exactly these function are called? My start and end values are dynamically calculated and I am not too sure how to pass them to Transition or how should I assign them to a view to make transition capture them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself:

I debugged deeper with Android's own transitions and found out both callbacks `captureStartValues` and `captureEndValues` do not happen in one animation. `captureStartValues` will be called for fragment exit animation `captureEndValues` will be called for fragment enter animation. So For example:

```
incomingFragment.apply {
    this.exitTransition = Slide(Gravity.TOP) // This will use 'captureEndValues' in Slide Transition
}
fragmentManager.beginTransation() { ... } // Will invoke the call
```

The start values of the transition will be view's current position. Although you can set start values in transition by using some computation.